# Ruby on Rails - Image translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, carrierwave

Have a Ruby on Rails app with carrierwave and imagemagick for image upload.  In my app, when I click to save record with the image upload, get an error "Image translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error".  Seeing this on a Heroku deploy.  I had this issue on both my local machine and on cloud9 Rails instance, which I resolved by manually running install of imagemagick.  Not sure how I would do that on heroku.

Welcome comments, questions, suggestions.

Gemfile contents below -

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3' 
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'

end
```

Comment: Imagemagick has to be installed on your machine and on remote machine too. This is not a gem. This is not ruby code. Though Heroku stack includes a version of Imagemagick by default. Can you confirm your code now works locally since you have installed Imagemagick on your machine ? Check your Heroku stack to make sure it is not a too old stack.

Comment: @Maxence Yes, after installing on local machine and cloud9 Rails instance, the code works great on resizing.  If I remove the resize line from image_uploader.rb, I can save the record to the database.

Comment: So now It is only on Heroku you have issues ? You should check your Heroku stack (if it's too old, your Imagemagick version is maybe too old too). I used to have problems resizing with Paperclip locally, but since it was fixed, no issue showed up on Heroku...

Comment: @Maxence Thanks - yes, Heroku deploy is where the issue is.  I don't know if or how I could run the update to imagemagick like I did locally.  Can you advise?  Also please detail "check your Heroku stack".

Comment: Heroku has Imagemagick by default. But the version of Imagemagick dépends on the stack that you run on Heroku. Connect to your Heroku account and try to see the stack name such as `Cedar 14` or such. For exampl here you can see what versions are running on Heroku : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages for two popular stacks

Comment: @Maxence settings show stack is heroku-16.    How would I update the imagemagick version?